# WordPress Media endpoint POST request by $.ajax() method saying "Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type."

Tags: jquery, ajax, media, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to publish CPT (custom post type) posts from front end with ajax and Rest API. I can create post titles and content without any issues but I need help uploading featured images. I am using $.ajax() method.
Not sure in what format I should send attachment URL as 'data' value. Here I have prepared an object where I put the attachment path with a key of 'source_url'. Is this okay?

And after submit the request, I am getting this error:
"Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type." [Note: I have uploaded an image with .jpeg extension]

Please kindly review my code and let me know what I am missing.
Thanks a lot.

````
var featuredImage = {
      source_url: $(".post-thumb").val(),
    };

    // Lets make an Ajax call to add image on the media
    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", sovObj.restNonce);
      },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
        "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="image.jpg"',
      },
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      url: sovObj.restURL + "wp/v2/media",
      type: "POST",
      data: featuredImage,
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
    });```
````

Comment: The issue may be with the value of the "source_url" variable in the "featuredImage" object. You are using jQuery's val() method to get the value, which is used to get the value of form elements such as input fields. It is possible that the source of the image is not being correctly passed in this variable.

You should check if the source_url value is correct and if it's referring to the correct image.
You can try to add a console.log(featuredImage) or console.log(featuredImage.source_url) before sending the request to see if the value is correctly passed.

Comment: @NandLal I have logged the console, and here it is
{source_url: 'C:\\fakepath\\10553881_790426624346811_8239904706690112830_o-1024x768.jpeg'}
I am sorry, event I don't know is it the right thing or not.

Comment: You are using an absolute path of the image, you should use a relative path instead. Are you using this on a server?